# How to fix Error #10123 when I run gatsby develop for gatsby-starter-gcn?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm trying to use gatsby-starter-gcn to create a website. At this point I just want to be able to view the starter site locally so I can begin to make edits. But when I run `gatsby develop` I get the following error:

```
ERROR #10123  CONFIG

We encountered an error while trying to load your site's gatsby-config. Please fix the error and try again.



  Error: Contentful space ID and access token need to be provided.

  - gatsby-config.js:14 Object.<anonymous>
    C:/Windows/system32/gatsby-starter-gcn/gatsby-config.js:14:11

  - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
    [gatsby-starter-gcn]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30

  - loader.js:1220 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10

  - loader.js:1049 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32

  - loader.js:937 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14

  - loader.js:1089 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19

  - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
    [gatsby-starter-gcn]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20

  - get-config-file.js:33 getConfigFile
    [gatsby-starter-gcn]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/get-config-file.js:33:20

  - index.js:134 module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-gcn]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:134:46

  - develop-process.js:433 module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-gcn]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/develop-process.js:433:36

  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5


not finished open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.052s
```

I tried to open the gatsby-config.js file in order to see the problem. I could open it in Notepad just fine, but Windows Script Host returned this error: 
Line: 1
Char: 5
Error: Expected ';'
Code: 800A03EC
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error

I think if I can fix this compilation error in this file my problem will probably be fixed, but I haven't been able to figure out how, since I'm not terribly experienced with javascript. Here's a link to the file on GitHub: https://github.com/ryanwiemer/gatsby-starter-gcn/blob/master/gatsby-config.js

Comment: I am not trying to use contentful either; I'm trying to use Netlify, but for some reason it still  tells me I need these contentful variables

Comment: If you don't want to use contentful I would recommend a different starter. You'll have to change all the queries to source from local .md or .mdx files. Without those variables your site you with probably get errors when trying to load it. Also Contentful is a CMS where Netlify is hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is being thrown because you may not have a `.env` file in your repository or windows environment variables set with your contentful SPACE_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN.

https://github.com/ryanwiemer/gatsby-starter-gcn/blob/master/gatsby-config.js#L7

Creating those variables should get this building for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need an `.env` file with `SPACE_ID` and `ACCESS_TOKEN` at the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The project requires a `.contentful.json` config file to be created in the root of the project. You can run `npm run setup` or `yarn setup` to have it walk you through the creation with you providing Contentful API key info. After that, running `gatsby develop` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I tried to integrate **Contentful** with my **Gatsby** project.

In order to fix this, follow the following steps:

1. Create .env.development

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=xxxxxxx
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxxxxxxx
```

2. Install `gatsby-source-contentful`, and your `gatsby-config.js` should looks like this.

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

/**
 * @type {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}
 */

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-image', // <-- required to be installed
    // your other plugins ...
  ],
};
```

3. You need to install `gatsby-plugin-image` plugin also.